# Geometry Shader only creates one primitive

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, transform-feedback

I am currently trying to use the geometry shader.

My input is a set of points, for which multiple triangle should be created

This is the geometry shader

```
#version 330
layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

in vec3[] vPos;
out vec3 oPos;

void main() {
    for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
        for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            for(int k = -1; k <= 1; k++)
            {
                oPos = vPos[0] + vec3(i,j,k);
                EmitVertex();
            }
        EndPrimitive();
        }

}
```

And this the corresponding C++ code

```
mMeshGenerator->use();

GLuint query;
glGenQueries(1, &query);
glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, mMeshVBO->buffer());
glBeginQuery(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_PRIMITIVES_WRITTEN, query);
    glBeginTransformFeedback(GL_TRIANGLES);
        mPointsVAO->draw();
    glEndTransformFeedback();
glEndQuery(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_PRIMITIVES_WRITTEN);
glFlush();
GLuint primitives;
glGetQueryObjectuiv(query, GL_QUERY_RESULT, &primitives);

std::cout << "-----" << primitives << "-----" << std::endl;
GLfloat feedback[primitives*3*3];
glGetBufferSubData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(feedback), feedback);

for (int i = 0; i < primitives*3*3; i++) {
    printf("%f\n", feedback[i]);
}
glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
```

According to the query only one primitive is written.

Output for input point (10,20,30):

```
-----1-----
9.000000
19.000000
29.000000
9.000000
19.000000
30.000000
9.000000
19.000000
31.000000
```

Whats wrong with my code that there is only 1 triangle instead of 27?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;
```

this means only 3 vertices (a.k.a. 1 triangle) will be allowed to be emitted; all the rest is discarded